# How to convert a list of lists to a dictionary with redundant keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists, called `my_list`:

```
['sit', (1, 1)]
['laboris', (2, 1)]
['nisi', (2, 1)]
['est', (4, 1)]
['qui', (4, 1)]
['cillum', (3, 1)]
['voluptate', (3, 1)]
['eu', (3, 1)]
['irure', (3, 1)]
['sunt', (4, 1)]
['reprehenderit', (3, 1)]
['nulla', (3, 1)]
['sint', (4, 1)]
['fugiat', (3, 1)]
['dolore', (2, 1)]
['dolore', (3, 1)]
['enim', (2, 1)]
['occaecat', (4, 1)]
['tempor', (2, 1)]
['commodo', (2, 1)]
['non', (4, 1)]
['minim', (2, 1)]
['aute', (3, 1)]
['ut', (2, 2)]
['ex', (2, 1)]
['deserunt', (4, 1)]
['ea', (2, 1)]
['eiusmod', (2, 1)]
['culpa', (4, 1)]
['labore', (2, 1)]
['mollit', (4, 1)]
['officia', (4, 1)]
['cupidatat', (4, 1)]
['adipiscing', (2, 1)]
['amet', (1, 1)]
['et', (2, 1)]
['ad', (2, 1)]
['consectetur', (2, 1)]
['anim', (4, 1)]
['magna', (2, 1)]
['quis', (2, 1)]
['ullamco', (2, 1)]
['dolor', (1, 1)]
['dolor', (3, 1)]
['aliquip', (2, 1)]
['velit', (3, 1)]
['ipsum', (1, 1)]
['incididunt', (2, 1)]
['sed', (2, 1)]
['id', (4, 1)]
['esse', (3, 1)]
['exercitation', (2, 1)]
['nostrud', (2, 1)]
```

I have tried:

```
d = {}

for item in all_lists:
    d[item[0]] = item[1:]

print (d)
```

But this overwrites a key, instead of updating that value. For example, `dolor` becomes: `{'dolor': [(3,1)]` instead of the desired goal of: `{'dolor': (3,1), (1,1), etc...}`

Ideally, the dictionary shape would not include a list of tuples as the value, but if need be.

How can I convert that list of lists to a dict in the format I would like?

I have observed [Python: List of lists to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191817/python-list-of-lists-to-dictionary) but that yielded me the incorrect I have right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list to dictionary conversion with multiple values per key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378231/list-to-dictionary-conversion-with-multiple-values-per-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use defaultdict feature:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Not tested code!

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for item in all_lists:
    d[item[0]].append(item[1:])

print (d)
```

Comment: It wraps each tuple into extra list. e.g. `{'sit': [[(1, 1)], [(2, 2)]], 'laboris': [[(2, 1)]]}`

Comment: How to fix? @ovgolovin

Comment: @JerryM. `append(item[1])` instead of `append(item[1:])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in case the keys are already sorted (it looks like they are):

```
import itertools as it
result = {k: [x[1] for x in v] for k, v in it.groupby(test, key=lambda x: x[0])}
```

Comment: What if not sorted all the time? (In this case yes, but I think we are lucky)

Comment: @JerryM. You can always use `sorted` beforehand but for large lists with many different keys this might hurt performance and it's better to use `defaultdict` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to add new key-value pair if `d` is missing this key with value being empty list `[]`. Then append new value to that list.

Python has [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to do that.

```
all_lists = [
    ['sit', (1, 1)],
    ['sit', (2, 2)],
    ['laboris', (2, 1)]
]

d = {}
for key, new_value in all_lists:
    values = d.setdefault(key, [])
    values.append(new_value)

print(d)


{
 'sit': [(1, 1), (2, 2)], 
 'laboris': [(2, 1)]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's annoying but you can change the `list` to a `tuple` with a quick call to the constructor.

```
a = [
    ['sit', (1, 1)],
    ['laboris', (2, 1)],
    ['nisi', (2, 1)],
    ['est', (4, 1)],
    ['qui', (4, 1)],
    ['cillum', (3, 1)],
    ['voluptate', (3, 1)],
    ['eu', (3, 1)],
    ['irure', (3, 1)],
    ['sunt', (4, 1)],
    ['reprehenderit', (3, 1)],
    ['nulla', (3, 1)],
    ['sint', (4, 1)],
    ['fugiat', (3, 1)],
    ['dolore', (2, 1)],
    ['dolore', (3, 1)],
    ['enim', (2, 1)],
    ['occaecat', (4, 1)],
    ['tempor', (2, 1)],
    ['commodo', (2, 1)],
    ['non', (4, 1)],
    ['minim', (2, 1)],
    ['aute', (3, 1)],
    ['ut', (2, 2)],
    ['ex', (2, 1)],
    ['deserunt', (4, 1)],
    ['ea', (2, 1)],
    ['eiusmod', (2, 1)],
    ['culpa', (4, 1)],
    ['labore', (2, 1)],
    ['mollit', (4, 1)],
    ['officia', (4, 1)],
    ['cupidatat', (4, 1)],
    ['adipiscing', (2, 1)],
    ['amet', (1, 1)],
    ['et', (2, 1)],
    ['ad', (2, 1)],
    ['consectetur', (2, 1)],
    ['anim', (4, 1)],
    ['magna', (2, 1)],
    ['quis', (2, 1)],
    ['ullamco', (2, 1)],
    ['dolor', (1, 1)],
    ['dolor', (3, 1)],
    ['aliquip', (2, 1)],
    ['velit', (3, 1)],
    ['ipsum', (1, 1)],
    ['incididunt', (2, 1)],
    ['sed', (2, 1)],
    ['id', (4, 1)],
    ['esse', (3, 1)],
    ['exercitation', (2, 1)],
    ['nostrud', (2, 1)]
]

final = {}
for l in a:
    final[l[0]]=tuple(l[1:])[0]

print(final)
```

prints

```
{'sit': (1, 1), 'laboris': (2, 1), 'nisi': (2, 1), 'est': (4, 1), 'qui': (4, 1), 'cillum': (3, 1), 'voluptate': (3, 1), 'eu': (3, 1), 'irure': (3, 1), 'sunt': (4, 1), 'reprehenderit': (3, 1), 'nulla': (3, 1), 'sint': (4, 1), 'fugiat': (3, 1), 'dolore': (3, 1), 'enim': (2, 1), 'occaecat': (4, 1), 'tempor': (2, 1), 'commodo': (2, 1), 'non': (4, 1), 'minim': (2, 1), 'aute': (3, 1), 'ut': (2, 2), 'ex': (2, 1), 'deserunt': (4, 1), 'ea': (2, 1), 'eiusmod': (2, 1), 'culpa': (4, 1), 'labore': (2, 1), 'mollit': (4, 1), 'officia': (4, 1), 'cupidatat': (4, 1), 'adipiscing': (2, 1), 'amet': (1, 1), 'et': (2, 1), 'ad': (2, 1), 'consectetur': (2, 1), 'anim': (4, 1), 'magna': (2, 1), 'quis': (2, 1), 'ullamco': (2, 1), 'dolor': (3, 1), 'aliquip': (2, 1), 'velit': (3, 1), 'ipsum': (1, 1), 'incididunt': (2, 1), 'sed': (2, 1), 'id': (4, 1), 'esse': (3, 1), 'exercitation': (2, 1), 'nostrud': (2, 1)}
```

Comment: This fails with the example (`dolor`) I posted.

Comment: `dict` cannot contain duplicate keys as the strings would have the same hash.  If you want to key the `dict` by something else then ok but attempting to write a second value with the same key will always fail.

Comment: Unless it is contained as a tuple of tuples or a list of tuples, as others have posted.