# How to convert an custom class object to a tuple in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

If we define `__str__` method in a class:

```py
    class Point():
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y


        def __str__(self, key):
            return '{}, {}'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

We will be able to define how to convert the object to the `str` class (into a string):

```py
    a = Point(1, 1)
    b = str(a)
    print(b)
```

I know that we can define the string representation of a custom-defined object, but how do we define the list —more precisely, tuple— representation of an object?

Comment: Give us some example code of something you would like to convert to a tuple so we can help. Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836128/python-convert-list-to-tuple -> It is specific to lists but it might help you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `tuple` "function" (it's really a type, but that means you can call it like a function) will take any iterable, including an iterator, as its argument. So if you want to convert your object to a tuple, just make sure it's iterable. This means implementing an `__iter__` method, which should be a generator function (one whose body contains one or more `yield` expressions). e.g.

```
>>> class SquaresTo:
...     def __init__(self, n):
...         self.n = n
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for i in range(self.n):
...             yield i * i
...
>>> s = SquaresTo(5)
>>> tuple(s)
(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)
>>> list(s)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> sum(s)
30
```

You can see from the example that several Python functions/types will take an iterable as their argument and use the sequence of values that it generates in producing a result.

Comment: I find we can [define `__getitem__` method to make the class iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python) too.

Comment: I explained the iteration protocols in [a talk to PyData London](https://github.com/steveholden/iteration) earlier this year. It might help - there is [also a video of the session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTwrF1DofCY).