# Magic method to destructure and assign values in python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

We could easily de-structure and assign variables using Python's builtin classes like list or tuples as seen below.

```py
a, b = 1, 2
```

However, in cases where we do not wish to inherit those classes, and want our container to have a similar behaviour as seen in the snippet below, how would we do so? Is there a magic method?

```py
class MyClass:
    ...

instance = MyClass()

# assuming there are some properties in the class for this
a, b = instance
```

An example that comes to mind would be dataclasses (although we could already do it with NamedTuple)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    name: str
    age: int

instance = MyClass("John", 10)
name, age = instance
```

Comment: You just need to make your instances *iterable* - so `__iter__()` is the method to implement.  You can borrow the iterator implementation of some other container, so `return iter([self.name, self.age])` would be a working example.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639363/how-to-convert-an-custom-class-object-to-a-tuple-in-python

Comment: @jasonharper, you're right - it can be done via the __iter__ method.