# How to make a Python class act like an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I would like to create a class that, when I call without the double brackets, returns a value in any context, just like what `str` or `int` does. For example, what can I do to make this possible:

```py
>>> class color:
...     def __init__(self, r, g, b):
...         self.r = r
...         self.g = g
...         self.b = b
...     def whatever_it_is(self):
...         return (self.r, self.g, self.b) # Class returns tuple
>>> myColor = color(16, 32, 64)
>>> myColor.g
32
>>> myColor
(16, 32, 64)
>>> color(5, 68, 37)
(5, 68, 37)
```

My goal is to create a color class compatible with Pygame. For example, I could do `mySurface.fill(color(16, 32, 64))`, which would be the same as `mySurface.fill((16, 32, 64))`. My color class is like `pygame.math.Vector2`, but written in Python and not C.

> *As well as this, I have a bonus question that doesn't need to be answered: **How do I make a class that can't be constructed?***

Is this possible in **Python 3.9**?

Final edit: The answer below does not work fully. Here is what I mean:

```
>>> myColor = color(1, 2, 3)
>>> myColor
(1, 2, 3)
>>> myColor.g
2
>>> myColor.g = 4
>>> myColor
(1, 2, 3)
>>> myColor.g
4
```

I have found out about the `__iter__` magic method and  my highest priority was Pygame compatibility by converting a class to a tuple, so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37639615/14913991) help you ?

Comment: **How do I make a class that can't be constructed**, what do you mean by this? You can just not define a constructor (`__init__` method)

Comment: @limserhane I want to call the class like `thisClass` to get a value without conversion using `tuple()` and such.

Comment: @Countour-Integral I don't want to do this `myClass()` and then do stuff like `aClass.thisProperty = thisValue`.

Comment: You could make your class an *extension* of tuple, or in this case just use the existing [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) in `collections`. Or make your class a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence), like tuples are. But there's no magic method for what you're asking because how would you distinguish between when you're supposed to be accessing the instance and when the value it wraps?

Comment: So you want to use **methods** of a class (or just variables) without creating an instance of it?

Comment: @TomKarzes no, because then it might *look like* a tuple but wouldn't be accepted by a method that accepts one.

Comment: Why do you want to create a class that works as a tuple if you can simply use tuples? mycol = (16,43,200)  and then use mycol ... you can create it as constant somewhere and use it ... creating a class simply to have a class makes no sense to me?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then how can I construct a class like `a(b, c, d)` instead of `a((b, c, d))` from inheriting a tuple or add methods to a namedtuple?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I would like to add methods to it.

Comment: You can inherit from a namedtuple, too; the docs show it.

Comment: @BlueStaggo About your "final edit": That's because `tuple`s are immutable. You can similary inherit from `list` and achieve what you want. Asking a question and after receiving an answer, editing it to ask *another* question is not how this site works. The answer was covering all the requirements that are mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You want your class to be act like a `tuple` but you also want to add some custom attributes to reach color codes (i.e `myColor.g`). In this case you can subclass `tuple` and write a custom `__new__`:

```
class color(tuple):
    def __new__ (cls, r, g, b):
        # Here we are saying that initialize a new tuple with
        # arguments we provided. tuple expects one parameter
        # so we are sending r, g, b as one parameter: (r, g, b)
        return super(color, cls).__new__(cls, (r, g, b))

    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        # Then we can add whatever attribute we like to our tuple.
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

>>> myColor = color(16, 32, 64)
>>> myColor.g
32
>>> myColor
(16, 32, 64)
>>> myColor == (16, 32, 64)
True
```

As suggested by kaya3 in the comments, the same thing can be achieved by using `namedtuple`s:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> color = namedtuple('color', ('r', 'g', 'b'))
>>> myColor = color(16, 32, 64)
>>> myColor.g
32
>>> myColor
color(r=16, g=32, b=64)
>>> myColor == (16, 32, 64)
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish you could explain what is happening in the __new__ method. I do not know much about how super() works.

Comment: @BlueStaggo You can check the edit. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: This is a longwinded way of creating a `collections.namedtuple`.

Comment: @kaya3 I didn't know `namedtuple`s can do this. I'll edit the post to mention about it. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly shorter way: `namedtuple('color', 'r g b')` since the constructor accepts a string of space-separated attribute names.