# To make tuple but it's hard

Tags: python-2.7, list, python-3.x, types, tuples

I just want to make tuple to using list
so,

```
list1 = [1,2]
a = tuple(list1)
```

I used this code but it's error..

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Why don't make tuple?

Comment: Works for me.  Try again as edited.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you've defined a variable of _type_ `tuple` _named_ `tuple`. This name is then shadowing the `tuple` built-in when you try to use it again. __Don't shadow built-in function names__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this question [Convert list to tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836128/convert-list-to-tuple-in-python)

You by sure called a variable like `list` or `tuple`, those words are built in types and can be redefined, which is a great source of errors

by example:

```
list = [1,3]
tuple = (2,3)
```

only this peace of code, works fine, but if you try to do

```
list = [1,3]
tuple = (2,3)
a = tuple(list)
```

you will get the error

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

other posible scenario:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
print(list)

$[1,2,3,4]
```

but:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
print(list)
other_list = list((1,2,3,4))
print(other_list)
```

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

because you redefined `list` and now is an object, the object `[1,2,3,4]`

the solution is simple, rename your variables, example:

```
lst = [1,3]
tpl = (4,5)
a = tuple(lst)
print(a)

$(1,3)
```

Comment: @wooojuns if you can, add the part of your code that was missing in your question, the one that breaks