# Inserting List as Individual Elements into Tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a tuple from a few different elements where one of them is a list, but I want this list to be transformed into individual elements as the tuple is created.

```
a = range(0,10)
b = 'a'
c = 3
tuple_ex = (a,b,c)
```

**The stored values in the tuple_ex are:** ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'a', 3)

**The values I desired to be stored in the tuple_ex are:** (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 3)

Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to code it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836128/convert-list-to-tuple-in-python this might help you

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I can't see how it can help me. I need to be able to create a tuple that contains the whole list plus some other elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Python3's unpacking:

```
a = range(0,10)
b = 'a'
c = 3
t = (*a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 3)
```

For Python2:

```
import itertools
t = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else i for i in (a, b, c)]))
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tuple(list(a) + [b] + [c])
```