# Python convert list to a list of tuple & tuple to list of tuple

Tags: python

How do I convert a **list**

```
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

to **list of tuple**

```
    [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

And 
convert a **tuple**

```
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

to **list of tuple**

```
    [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert list to tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836128/convert-list-to-tuple-in-python)

Comment: @MauricioCortazar no it is not..pls compare both the questions carefully.

Comment: is not the same, but you can find the answer easily on the internet

Comment: @MauricioCortazar give me the url if u can find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from list:

```
[tuple(x)]
```

from tuple:

```
[x]
```

---

i.e.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> [tuple(x)]
[(1, 2, 3)]
>>> x = (1, 2, 3)
>>> [x]
[(1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: `[tuple(x)]` will work whether `x` is a list, a tuple, or any other iterable.

Comment: @chepner but slightly slower if you already know the input is a tuple. However very valid point :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(arr)
tpl = (arr,)
print(type(tpl), tpl)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
<class 'tuple'> ([1, 2, 3, 4],)
```

case 2:

```
tpl_2 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
print(tpl_2)
arr_2 = [tpl_2]
print(type(arr_2), arr_2)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
<class 'list'> [(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing the following:-

```
your_list = [1,2,3,4]
new_list = [tuple(your_list)]
```

And in the second case:-

```
your_tuple = (1,2,3,4)
new_list = [your_tuple]
```

Answer (score 0):

try it !

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
t=tuple(i for i in l)
t
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and

```
tl = [t]
tl
```

output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```