# Create list of tuples from two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists of coordinates:

> [37.773972, -122.431297]

> [37.773972, -122.45]

I want to create a list of tuples like so:

> [(37.773972, -122.431297), (37.773972, -122.45)]

I've tried using zip but that merges the two.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list to tuple in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836128/convert-list-to-tuple-in-python)

Comment: Doesn't that just convert a list to a tuple? I have two lists and want to create list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> lst1 = [37.773972, -122.431297]
>>> lst2 = [37.773972, -122.45]
>>> res = [tuple(lst1), tuple(lst2)]
>>> res
[(37.773972, -122.431297), (37.773972, -122.45)]
```

Comment: What if the two lists are tuples, is there a way to create the list of tuples then?

Comment: You would just pass them as is. Assume they are called t1 and t2, `res = [t1,t2]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
l1 = [37.773972, -122.431297]
l2 = [37.773972, -122.45]

merged = [tuple(l1), tuple(l2)]

print(merged)  # [(37.773972, -122.431297), (37.773972, -122.45)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a list into tuple using tuple(list name).
Like:

```py
def convert(list):

    return tuple(list)

  
list = [a, c, b, d]

print(convert(list))
```

Here I define a function which is stored as a list and then I return it as a tuple. I give the input for list and finally when I print the defined function, It displays a tuple format of the list given.

Answer (score 0):

**list1** = [37.773972, -122.431297]

**list2** = [37.773972, -122.45]

**tup**=[tuple(list1),tuple(list2)]

**print(tup)**